# Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction<string>' to `UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction'

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to send arguments through the standard Unity listener, as per the tutorial.

```
mbListener = new UnityAction<string>(SomeFunction);

void SomeFunction(string _message)
{
    Debug.Log ("Some Function was called!");
}
```

Why is this failing with the above error message?
BTW I am looking for practical answers and really don't care for tech-talk.

(NB Unity's own manual says it can handle arguments but I cannot work out why this is wrong).

Comment: What is the type of `mbListener`? Is it `UnityAction`? (the non generic one)

Comment: `private UnityAction mbListener;`

Comment: Well, the answer already appeared based on this assumption, so that should help

Comment: It does and it doesn't - the event manager class only allows UnityActions with no args... I assumed that establishing the listener with arguments would allow args to be passed as part of the AddListener function.

Answer (score 2):

What did you declare `mbListener` as? Probably its of type - `UnityAction`. Declaring it as `UnityAction` and assigning it with `UnityAction<string>` is causing you the problem.

Based on your requirement, You can do either of these 2 to fix -

```
UnityAction<string> mbListener = new UnityAction<string>(SomeFunction);
```

or

```
UnityAction mbListener = new UnityAction(SomeFunction);
void SomeFunction()
{
    Debug.Log ("Some Function was called!");
}
```

**Edit**
As @MotoSV pointed out... you should call it by`mbListener("String parameter");`

mbListener is a place holder for any function/listner you wanted to call. When you need it to be called you just have to call the UnityAction variable passing the parameter to it. So `mbListener("String parameter");` will work for you.

Comment: `UnityAction<string> mbListener = new UnityAction<string>(SomeFunction);` clears the errors but how do I call the listener with string argument?

Comment: mbListener("you string parameter");